# Update Alpinejs x-data when input has a value on page load or user change

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm a little lost. I need to add a class to the label if the text input has a value, either on page load (if input is prefilled) or when user enters a vale. And I need to remove those classes if the user removes the text from the input.

```css
.has-value {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alpinejs/2.3.0/alpine.js"></script>

<form x-data='{value:false}'>
  <label for='example' :class='{"has-value": value }'>Label </label>
  <input id='example' name='example' type='text' x-on:change='value = true' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can use `x-model` attribute from `alpinejs` to bind the input text to alpine component property. Now we can check if the input has a value by checking its length.

```html
<form x-data='{value: ""}'>
    <label for='example' :class='{"has-value": value.length > 0 }'>Label </label>
    <input id='example' name='example' type='text' x-model="value" />
</form>
```

If you want to set an initial value for the input, you can do it in the alpinejs component as shown below

```html
<form x-data='{value: "initial-value"}'>
    <label for='example' :class='{"has-value": value.length > 0 }'>Label </label>
    <input id='example' name='example' type='text' x-model="value" />
</form>
```

Note that I have used `value.length > 0` since `has-value` class should be added if there is some input in the field.